# How To Only Accept Numbers For An Operator Using Generics In Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, custom-operator

I'm trying to create an operator for numbers. For example an operator that increments a number by 10.

This is the code I wrote:

```
prefix operator +++{}

prefix operator +++<T>(inout operand: T) -> T{
    operand += 10
    return operand
}
```

There is an error with my `+=` operator. it requires numeric operands. so I did this:

```
protocol Numeric {}

extension Int: Numeric {}
extension Float: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}

prefix operator +++ {}

prefix operator +++<T: Numeric>(inout operand: T) -> T {
    operand += 10
    return operand
}
```

But it failed to compile. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Nuneric is a protocol that has no requirements. I think it should work when you put `func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self` inside your protocol

Comment: @Kametrixom you also need `IntegerLiteralConvertible` so you can create a “10” of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Numeric` protocol does not guarantee a `+=` operator will be present.

Consider this:

```
// Numeric imposes no requirements, so this will compile
extension Range: Numeric { }
// but Range has no += operator, so +++ could not work
```

Instead, you would have to add `+=` as a requirement of `Numeric`:

```
protocol Numeric: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func +=(inout lhs: Self,rhs: Self)
}
```

Note, you also need `Numeric` to conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` so that you can create a `10` of the appropriate type to add to it.

Now, this compiles and runs fine, because `Numeric` guarantees all the features it uses will be available:

```
prefix operator +++{}

prefix func +++<T: Numeric>(inout operand: T) -> T {
    operand += 10
    return operand
}

var i = 10
+++i  // i is now 20
```

That said, there is already a protocol that does what you need: `Strideable`, to which all the standard numeric types conform.

```
protocol Strideable {
// (actually _Strideable but don’t worry about that)

    /// A type that can represent the distance between two values of `Self`.
    typealias Stride : SignedNumberType
    // note, SignedNumberType conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible

    /// Returns a `Self` `x` such that `self.distanceTo(x)` approximates
    /// `n`.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(1).
    ///
    /// - SeeAlso: `RandomAccessIndexType`'s `advancedBy`, which
    ///   provides a stronger semantic guarantee.
    func advancedBy(n: Self.Stride) -> Self
}
```

And an implementation of `+=` that uses it:

```
func +=<T : Strideable>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T.Stride)
```

This means you can implement `+++` like this:

```
prefix func +++<T: Strideable>(inout operand: T) -> T { 
    operand = operand.advancedBy(10)
    return operand 
}
```

Comment: You are missing the prefix keyword on func declaration

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks. One more thing. Where did you learned these? In other cases how can I solve the problem myself? There were no documentation about `Strideable` or `IntegerLiteralConverible`. :|

Comment: The std lib (where these protocols are defined) documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs10Strideable) - this is a new thing as of this June. You used to have to find stuff out by command-clicking things like `Int` in a playground to view the std lib headers.  [SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/Strideable/hierarchy/) is also good as it has hierarchy diagrams – it’s often useful to look at what protocols types like `Int` implement to find capabilities.

Comment: since now, you are my superhero. thank you very very much. :-*

Answer (score 5):

Heres a much cleaner and better way and works with everything from `Int8` to `CGFloat` and only uses standard library types so you don't need to manually conform to your own protocol:

```
prefix operator +++ {}    
prefix func +++<T where T: FloatingPointType, T.Stride: FloatingPointType>(inout operand: T) -> T {
    operand = operand.advancedBy(T.Stride(10))
    return operand
}

prefix func +++<T where T: IntegerArithmeticType, T: IntegerLiteralConvertible, T.IntegerLiteralType: IntegerLiteralConvertible>(inout operand: T) -> T {
    operand = operand + T(integerLiteral: 10)
    return operand
}
```

As @Airspeed Velocity pointed out you can also do it like this:

```
prefix operator +++ {}
prefix func +++<T: Strideable>(inout operand: T) -> T {
    operand = operand.advancedBy(10)
    return operand
}
```

Comment: This actually is real generics.

Comment: Consider returning `operand` as required by question.

Comment: Since `Strideable.Stride` is `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, you can do it in one shot as `prefix func +++<T: Strideable>(inout operand: T) -> T { operand = operand.advancedBy(10); return operand }`